# Closed form of the series $\sum\frac{\ln(n)}{n^a}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, zeta-functions

I want to know if there exists, and how to arrive at, a closed form of this infinite sum:
$$S_a=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\ln(n)}{n^a}$$
I know the series converges at least for every $a>1$ by the comparison test since $$S_a\le\int_1^\infty \frac{\ln(x)}{x^a}dx=\frac{1}{\left(1-a\right)^2}$$
But I have been thinking hard and I'm not reaching any results. 
The furthest I've gone is saying:$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^a} \ln\left(\frac{e}{n}\right)=\zeta(a)-S_a$$
Does anyone have any hints?
Thank you!

Comment: It's essentially the derivative of the zeta function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One may recall that the [Riemann zeta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function) 
$$
\zeta(a)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^a}
$$ is differentiable on $(1,\infty)$
admitting a derivative given by
$$
\zeta'(a)=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\ln n}{n^a}.
$$